# Linqpad query error

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I am an experienced SQL Developer trying to learn LINQ and particularly LINQPad.  I have created a simple MVC5 app and added a reference to Adventure Works 2012.  I have the following code in the Student Controller:

```
 namespace Linqpad.Controllers
    {
        public class PersonController : Controller
        {
            private AdventureWorks2012Entities db = new AdventureWorks2012Entities();

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var courses = db.Employees
                .Include(p => p.PurchaseOrderHeaders)
                .Where(p => p.Gender=="Male");
                return View();
            }
}
}
```

This works as expected.  I am now trying to run this in Linqpad, however I get the error below:
[image]

How can I refactor this query to run in Linqpad?

Comment: remove `var courses =` or try adding `;` to end of statement

Comment: Did you try changing Language to C# Statements per the error message's suggestion?  Not sure it will help, but it wouldn't take but a few seconds to try.

Comment: @JamieD77, if I do this it says: "Cannot execute text selection: The name 'db' does not exist in the current context".  I also incorporated Tims suggestion.

Comment: @Tim, please see above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the top toolbar, you have Language set to "C# Expression." This means that the expression in the window will automatically be evaluated and dumped to the output area. The `var courses =` is unnecessary in this mode.

If you set the Language mode to "C# Statements," now it will evaluate any statements you type, and will only output things if you add `.Dump()` to the end (or `Console.WriteLine`). So your statement would become:

```
    var courses = db.Employees
        .Include(p => p.PurchaseOrderHeaders)
        .Where(p => p.Gender=="Male")
        .Dump();
```

You can change the default Language mode in the Options > Query area.

Comment: Thanks, however the error I get now is: Could not load type 'Linqpad.AdventureWorks2012Entities' from assembly 'LINQPad, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21353812cd654db5'

Comment: @w0051977 That's a new question, and related to how you setup the Connection. Start a new question and add a screenshot of your connection setup.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Include` in LINQPad 5, you need to include a reference to EntityFramework.dll.  To do this,

1. Press F4 in the query window to view the Query Properties
2. Click `Add` in the `Additional References` window and select, or browse for `EntityFramework.dll`
3. Under `Additional Namespace Imports` add the namespace `System.Data.Entity`

After you do these steps, `Include` can be appended to your Table obect.

```
var courses = Employees
        .Include(p => p.PurchaseOrderHeaders)
        .Where(p => p.Gender=='M')
        .Dump();
```

use `Dump()` to get the output.  Also set Language to `C# Statment(s)`

Comment: Thanks, however the error I get now is: Could not load type 'Linqpad.AdventureWorks2012Entities' from assembly 'LINQPad, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21353812cd654db5'.

Comment: For future reference: LinqPad is C#, it supports *Include* just fine.

Comment: @JamieD77, are you able to answer my question in my comment above.  I just cannot get this to work.  Thanks.